# Pivoting mysql database with multiple data

Tags: php, mysql

My database looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------- +

| FIELD1                | FIELD2                |

+-----------------------+-----------------------+

| Submission ID         | Read                  |

| 159                   | Unread                |

| Nume si prenume       | PCU A GABRI           |

| Data nasterii         | 11-xxxxxxx            |

| Categoria de varsta   | 10-12 ani             |

| Localitatea           | TARGU JIU             |

| Judetul               | GORJ                  |

| Unitatea reprezentata | PALATUL C        TG-  |

| Solicit cazare        | Nu                    |

| Nr. cazati            |                       |

| divider               | Informatii melodie    |

| Titlul melodiei       | ROZ                   |

| Compozitor            | Robert Gergely        |

| Textier               | Ma                    |

| divider               | Date de contact       |

| Telefon               | 076                   |

| Email                 | cofi                  |

| Nume indrumator       | P                     |

| Telefon indurmator    | 0766xxxxxxxxxx        |

| Email indrumator      |                       |

| Nume insotitor        |                       |

| Negativ melodie       | 1                     |

| files                 | http:x                |

| 105                   | Unrea                 |

| Nume si prenume       | STxxxxxxxxxxxxx       |

| Data nasterii         | 03xxxxxxxxxxxx        |

| Categoria de varsta   | 13-15 ani             |

| Localitatea           | DR.TR.SEVERI          |

| Judetul               | MEHEDINTI             |

| Unitatea reprezentata | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRIN    |

| Solicit cazare        | Nu                    |

| Nr. cazati            |                       |

| divider               | Informatii melodie    |

| Titlul melodiei       | RISE LIKE A PHOENIX   |

| Compozitor            | REPERTORIU INTERNATIO |

| Textier               | COxxxxxxxxxxxxxx      |

| divider               | Date de contact       |

| Telefon               | 07xxxxxxxxxxxxxx5     |

| Email                 | daxxxxxxxxxxxxx       |

| Nume indrumator       | CRxxxxxxxxxx          |

| Telefon indurmator    | 07xxxxxxx             |

| Email indrumator      |                       |

| Nume insotitor        | Sxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       |

| Negativ melodie       | 1                     |

| files                 | http://x              |

| 104                   | Unread                |

| Nume si prenume       | Bxxxxxxxxxra          |

| Data nasterii         | 17-x                  |

| Categoria de varsta   | 13-15 ani             |

| Localitatea           | xxxxxxxxxxxx          |

| Judetul               | Gorj                  |

| Unitatea reprezentata | Paxxxxxxxxxu          |

| Solicit cazare        | Nu                    |

| Nr. cazati            |                       |

| divider               | Informatii melodie    |

| Titlul melodiei       | And I Am Telling You  |

| Compozitor            | Rep. International    |

| Textier               | Rep. International    |

| divider               | Date de contact       |

| Telefon               | 076xxxxxxxxxx         |

| Email                 | elvxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     |

| Nume indrumator       | Paxxxe                |

| Telefon indurmator    | 076xxxx               |

| Email indrumator      | paxxxxxxxxxxx         |

| Nume insotitor        | Bolovan Elena         |

| Negativ melodie       | 1                     |

| files                 | http://muzica       3 |

| 178                   | Unread                |

+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

It was created by an online registration form at a school contest.
My problem is that I need to pivot the table and to convert data from rows to columns for each row like this:

```
 Nume si prenume       | Data nasterii         |  Categoria de varsta   | Localitatea  | | Judetul  |  Unitatea reprezentata | Solicit cazare    | Nr. cazati   | Titlul melodiei      | Compozitor        | Textier          | Date de contact       | Telefon        | Email       | Nume indrumator     | Telefon indurmator    | Email indrumator      | Nume insotitor        | Negativ melodie       | files
```

For an easy understanding of the problem, my database contains the data this way:

```
| FIELD1                | FIELD2                |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| id                    | Read                  |
| Name                  | PCU A GABRI           |
| Date                  | 11-xxxxxxx            |
| Age                   | 10-12 ani             |
| .............more rows here...........        |
| id                    | Read                  |
| Name                  | xxxxxxxxxxx           |
| Date                  | another data          |
| Age                   |                       |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

..and my goal is to pivot the rows as column this way:

```
| id                    | name                  | Date                  | Age                   |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| data                  | data                  | data                  | data                  |
| data                  | data                  | data                  | data                  |
| data                  | data                  | data                  | data                  |
| data                  | data                  | data                  | data                  |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: OK. Seriously. You have no PRIMARY KEY. You will need to fix that first.

Comment: that is not a problem. The form was so bad implemented, but I can work anything on the database.

Comment: Well, if you can change anything, then I would be tempted to switch from this EAV model to a more conventional structure - in which the 'keys' are columns to begin with.

Comment: as you can see, normally, the stupid form does have a ID.. the row after Submission ID is the ID :(

Comment: Well after that you would return the results in exactly the way you would expect.

Comment: I've edited the question for a better understanding.

Comment: I'm not sure what more we can add to this by way of an answer at this point.